# Android Studio Not Applying My Design Changes

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, manifest

I'm trying to change the theme of some activities by removing the action bar or changing the title of it. At first i was doing it using the AppTheme option in the design tab. However, after searching online i knew that i was doing it the wrong way, so i proceeded to the AndroidManifest file to do my changes manually. Unfortunately, it's not working either. Here's the code of my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.wonderheart">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="Sign Up"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:label="Log In"/>

        <activity android:name=".drawable.welcome">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".UserProfile"
                  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".HomePage" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here are some of my activities that I'm trying to change:
[Action Bar Title Changed Successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho2Uj.png)
[Action Bar Title Didn't Change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whPjS.png)

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Preview and Kotlin. I hope you can help because i can't progress on my work without fixing this design issue!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix problem two way.
1. Use common one theme for all activities and use code for hiding and showing action bar in onCreate method

```
   // Set up the toolbar
 val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
         var actionBar = supportActionBar

        //For hiding android actionbar
        actionBar.hide();

        //For showing android actionbar
        //actionBar.show();
```

2. Use custom style for activity where you don’t want to show action bar in example below I did it for application level but you can use it your way with your any other activities

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name = "AppTheme" parent = "android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name = "NoActionBar" parent = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup = "true"
    android:icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label = "@string/app_name"
    android:theme = "@style/NoActionBar"   <!--This is the important line-->
    >
    <activity
```